# How to copy msgid to msgstr in gettext to make django i18n/translation?

Tags: django, internationalization, translation, gettext, django-i18n

In Django i18n for JavaScript "djangojs" there is false assumption that only language is English - https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20280.

Because of this limitation if my language is not English I have to copy all msgid to msgstr just after string extraction. I was searching internet but found nothing about it.

**Is there any tool which I could run on *.po file which will copy all msgid to msgstr?**

I need translate Polish into Polish since if I will not do Django will translate Polish JavaScript into English - what is wrong. All your suggestion is welcome.

---

Example - Polish *.po:

```
msgid "Polski"
msgstr ""
```

Should be:

```
msgid "Polski"
msgstr "Polski"
```

If it is not be done:
Polski = Polish what is invalid:

If it is done Polski = Polski!

This need is because Django loads English first than update translation if Polish translation is empty nothing is translated even it is not required. All languages other than English should be done with this trick.

Answer (score 5):

yes, it's part of gettext and is called msgen:
http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/msgen-Invocation.html